# Microsoft Graph SDK get site url after group is created

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to retrieve the site url when a microsoft-365 group is created in sharepoint using graph sdk. I read from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that in order to access a group team site I should use `GET /groups/{group-id}/sites/root` BUT I don't know how to do it.

Also I have tried code below but throws exception that resource was not found.

```
var site = await graphClient.Sites[$"/groups/{group.Id}/sites/root"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

I would like to know if I can modify the code above and use the group id to retrieve the active site url.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 graphClient.Groups["0745be26-2d8a-4f8d-be2d-37356a4794a3"].Sites["root"].Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

My test result:
[image]